# NetworkManager/dhcp4 logs lease info to /var/log/messages every 30 minutes, how to reduce logging

Tags: logs, networkmanager, dhcp

Running OL8 (same as RHEL8, CentOS 8, etc.), I see about 30 lines added to /var/log/messages every 30 minutes. I don't see it reporting a problem so I don't see why it does that so frequently. Do I have a way to tell it how often to log? Here is what I get:

```
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6685] dhcp4 (eth0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '3600'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6686] dhcp4 (eth0): option domain_name          => '**********.com'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option domain_name_servers  => '10.25.8.10'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option expiry               => '1612282497'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option host_name            => 'ip-10-25-0-208'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option interface_mtu        => '9001'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option ip_address           => '10.25.0.208'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6687] dhcp4 (eth0): option ntp_servers          => '23.239.24.67 128.138.141.172 198.55.111.50'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6688] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_routers    => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6689] dhcp4 (eth0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6690] dhcp4 (eth0): option routers              => '10.25.0.1'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6690] dhcp4 (eth0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.254.0'
Feb  2 10:14:57 tbdgprxy NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1612278897.6690] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed extended -> extended
```

Comment: what is the level equals to in your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?

Comment: I have not changed the conf file. The [logging] section has "level" and "domains" settings that are both commented out, so it's using the default values.